# Convert value to time format in R

Tags: r, time-series, strptime

I have values in the format "221559460" where first two is hour, other two is minute and following digits are in milliseconds. Is there any shortcut method to convert to time-series format without manually appending ":" in the value and calculating second from millisecond digits in R?

Comment: what exactly is your expected output

Comment: "22:15:59.460" is the expected output and R identifying it as time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot avoid some parsing here due to not having the "seconds" part, but it can be done fairly easily even with a simple regular expression:

```
> sub(pattern     = '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]*)',
+     replacement = '\\1:\\2:\\3.\\4',
+     x           = 221559460)
[1] "22:15:59.460"

> strptime(
+     x = sub(pattern     = '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]*)',
+             replacement = '\\1:\\2:\\3.\\4',
+             x           = 221559460),
+     format = '%H:%M:%OS')
[1] "2015-12-11 22:15:59 PST"
```

Updated answer based on below comment:

```
> options(digits.secs = 3)
> strptime(
+     x = sub(pattern     = '([0-9]{8})_([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]*)',
+             replacement = '\\1 \\2:\\3:\\4.\\5',
+             x           = '20150819_221559460'),
+     format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS')
[1] "2015-08-19 22:15:59.46 PDT"
```

Update for vectorized example:

```
> df <- data.frame(timestamp = paste('20150819', 221559460 + round(runif(10) * 100), sep = '_'))
> strptime(sub('([0-9]{3})$', '.\\1', df$timestamp),'%Y%m%d_%H%M%OS')
 [1] "2015-08-19 22:15:59.517 PDT" "2015-08-19 22:15:59.550 PDT"
 [3] "2015-08-19 22:15:59.538 PDT" "2015-08-19 22:15:59.493 PDT"
 [5] "2015-08-19 22:15:59.484 PDT" "2015-08-19 22:15:59.549 PDT"
 [7] "2015-08-19 22:15:59.510 PDT" "2015-08-19 22:15:59.462 PDT"
 [9] "2015-08-19 22:15:59.466 PDT" "2015-08-19 22:15:59.474 PDT"
```

Comment: My actual value was "20150819_221559460" where the first part in yy-mm-dd which i removed to simplify. As you have the date part in the output, can I use the original data value?

Comment: @daroczig Simply calling `strptime("221559460", format="%H%M%S")` also gives same result. OP wants fractional part of seconds as well. Probably `options(digits.secs = 3)` can help.

Comment: @daroczig we are missing the milliseconds value.

Comment: Thanks @Narendra, I've just updated my answer. Ngeunpo, please also see the above updates based on your comment.

Comment: A simpler substitution `sub("(.{3})$", ".\\1", "20150819_221559460")` also works, when used with `format = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%OS"`.

Comment: I need to apply it to a column, can I use sapply for that?

Comment: Thanks @mvkorpel for the simpler regex -- see further example in the answer, although I like to have detailed regular expressions for validation. Ngeunpo -- please submit a new (or search for related) questions for how to apply this on a column, but as `sub` is vectorized, that's very easy -- see updated answer.